# Shall we participate in Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

It's that time of year again: [Winter Bash/hat
time](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com)!  Here's the
summary:

> Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack
>   Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by
>   earning "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks
>   (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats
>   in a leaderboard

And here's some more detail:

> The event will run from 19 December 2016 up to and including 08
>   January 2017.  Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve
>   earned on (http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com). That site
>   will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other
>   details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don't want to participate, don't want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats"
>   option available.  And just like last time, at the end of the
>   event, all hats will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will
>   be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the
>   footer.

Our default option at Emacs.SE is *to participate* in Winter Bash.
Please take a moment to vote *yes* or *no* on our site-wide
participation (and/or comment on the options).  If there's a lot
of *no* votes, we can opt out collectively.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### `t`

```
(when (hatp)
  (wear-fun-hats))
```

Comment: It looks like participation in a landslide.  Enjoy your hats starting on the 19th!

Answer (score 1):

#### `nil`

```
(when (grinchp)
  (steal-hoo-hash))
```